# Simulate capacitive touch sensitivity and noise immunity

Tags: touch, qtouch

Due to covid, we are limited in the time we can tune our touch designs before EMC tests.

The device we are using has a PC based analyzer that is connected to the device over a serial protocol. Normally we use this analyzer when tuning for sensitivity and noise, but we are now forced to use simulation software as much as possible.

Is it possible to emulate a physical device by sending capacitance values from our simulation software to the analyzer and then tune the device based on this data?

The simulator we are using is COMSOL, and we are using Microchip touch devices.

Comment: Is it possible questions get vague answers, please be specific and edit the question. also they're not very many comsol users on this site.

Comment: Do you want to test PCB effects(ground plane etc.) or electrode dimensions or enviromental effects(RF noise etc.)? Please give more information about your HW and touch button IC specifically.

Comment: yes you could or Depending on the sensitivity use a switched power diode with large 0V capacitance and small reverse capacitance  with a discharge load R AC coupled to simulate it. Maybe...